# DriverManager автоматически ищет драйвера только при старте?

Tags: java, sql, tomcat

При попытке получить `connection` через `DriverManager` получал `SQLException`. Это все на *tomcat*. Драйвер `postgresql` грузил через maven в web проект.
В общем до меня дошло, то что надо скинуть postgresql.jar в директорию *lib* сервера *tomcat8*. Работать-то работает, но пара вопросов есть.
1) `DriverManager`(или `ServiceProvider`) ищет драйвера в момент старта *VM*(это момент когда *tomcat* включается) и все?
2) Есть ли опасность хранения двух одинаковых `postgresql` в папке `lib` и в папке web приложения одновременно?

Answer (score 0):

Добавить зависимость посгре со скоупом runtime.

1. драйвера подгружаются при старте конкретного приложения
2. если версия одна, то опасности нет, но лучше их как зависимость добавить или в lib томкета положить.